# substract values of two nested dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I'd need to get delta of two nested dictionary:

I'm using a function like that to get a nested dictionary

```
def _get_data(self):
    duplicates = defaultdict(list) # to append tuples into a dictionary
    counter_dict = AutoVivification()
    vpls_dict = AutoVivification()

    fpcs = self._get_slot_fpcs_online()
    pattern = "GOT:\s+(\d+).*([0-9A-F]{2,2}\:[0-9A-F]{1,2}\:[0-9A-F]{1,2}\:[0-9A-F]{1,2}\:[0-9A-F]{1,2}\:[0-9A-F]{1,2})\s+\d{4}\s+(\d\s+\d).*(\d\s+\d+/\d+)"
    regex = re.compile(pattern,re.IGNORECASE)

    for i in fpcs:
        if i == '11':
            for pfe in range(2):
                cmd = self._conn.rpc.request_pfe_execute(target='fpc' + str(i),command='show l2metro '+str(pfe)+' mac hw')                  
                cmd_str = etree.tostring(cmd)
                for x in regex.findall(cmd_str):
                    if x[2] =='0   0' and x[3] != '7 255/255':  
                        duplicates[i].append(x)
        else:
            cmd = self._conn.rpc.request_pfe_execute(target='fpc' + str(i),command='show l2metro 0 mac hw') 
            cmd_str = etree.tostring(cmd)
            for x in regex.findall(cmd_str):
                if x[2] =='0   0' and x[3] != '7 255/255':  
                    duplicates[i].append(x)

    for k,v in duplicates.iteritems():
        for j in v:
            cmd_vpls = self._conn.rpc.get_l2_learning_routing_instances()
            vpls_instance = ''.join(cmd_vpls.xpath("//l2ald-rtb-entry[l2rtb-id=" + '"' + str(j[0]) + '"'"]/l2rtb-name//text()")[0])
            vpls_dict[k][j[1]][j[3]][j[0]][vpls_instance] = self._conn.cli('show configuration routing-instances '+ vpls_instance + ' forwarding-options family vpls filter',warning=False).split('\n')[1].replace('input','').replace(';','')
            counter_cmd = self._conn.rpc.get_firewall_filter_information(filtername=str(vpls_dict[k][j[1]][j[3]][j[0]][vpls_instance]).strip())
            counter_dict[k][j[1]][j[3]][vpls_instance][vpls_dict[k][j[1]][j[3]][j[0]][vpls_instance].strip()] = ''.join(counter_cmd.xpath('./filter-information/policer/packet-count//text()')).replace('\n','')
    return counter_dict
```

counter_dict result look likes:

{'10': {'00:07:72:9d:dc:4c': {'0 255/255': {'128379': {'CDALJ1/17223002010': '91304'}}},
        '00:0f:bb:fa:25:fd': {'0 255/255': {'232367': {'CDALJ1/14100001093228': '1585097'}}},
        '00:1b:c0:f2:f4:fa': {'0 255/255': {'156420': {'CDALJ1/08903762011': '0'},
                                            '166980': {'CDALJ1/19369922011': '0'}}},
        '88:e0:f3:61:d8:01': {'0 255/255': {'182099': {'CDALJ1/11274452012': '0'}}},
        'ec:13:db:0a:95:01': {'0 255/255': {'182099': {'CDALJ1/11274452012': '0'}}}},

'11': {'00:00:0c:07:ac:75': {'0 255/255': {'232173': {'CDALJ1/14100001093242': '0'}}},
        '00:00:0c:07:ac:f5': {'0 255/255': {'293667': {'CDALJ1/14100001095054': '2723092'}}},
        '00:00:0c:07:ac:f6': {'0 255/255': {'298967': {'CDALJ1/14100001095106': '0'}}},
        '00:00:0c:07:ac:f7': {'0 255/255': {'298969': {'CDALJ1/14100001095107': '0'}}},
        '00:07:72:9d:dc:4c': {'0 255/255': {'128379': {'CDALJ1/17223002010': '91304'}}}

[......]

I'm trying to get a delta of inner value keeping dictionary structure :

mac_dict1  = _get_data()

{'10': {'00:07:72:9d:dc:4c': {'0 255/255': {'128379': {'CDALJ1/17223002010': '91304'}}},
        '00:0f:bb:fa:25:fd': {'0 255/255': {'232367': {'CDALJ1/14100001093228': '1585097'}}}

sleep5

mac_dict2 = _get_data()

{'10': {'00:07:72:9d:dc:4c': {'0 255/255': {'128379': {'CDALJ1/17223002010': '91310'}}},
        '00:0f:bb:fa:25:fd': {'0 255/255': {'232367': {'CDALJ1/14100001093228': '1585100'}}}

result = get_diff(mac_dict1,mac_dict2)

result should be provide a result like that:

{'10': {'00:07:72:9d:dc:4c': {'0 255/255': {'128379': {'CDALJ1/17223002010': '6'}}},
        '00:0f:bb:fa:25:fd': {'0 255/255': {'232367': {'CDALJ1/14100001093228': '3'}}}

Could you provide me any hint or tip about how to do that (not the code)?

Thanks

Comment: It sure is possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: If you want to get a proper answer you better to update your question with the code that you've tried so far, and tell us about that problems that you've got with your code.

Comment: Not downvoting, but I got a bit annoyed by getting shown the code which "gets a nested dictionary", if that is not part of the question. The dicts you have (in a code block) and the result you expect, just like you are doing, is more than enough to get the point across. It even is an interesting question then, like niemmi's answer shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that with simple recursive function that will turn `str` values to `int` and subtract or recurse in case of `dict`:

```
def subtract(x, y):
    if isinstance(x, dict) and isinstance(y, dict):
        return {key: subtract(x[key], y[key]) for key in x if key in y}
    else:
        return str(int(x) - int(y))
```

Running it with given input:

```
d1 = {
    '10': {
        '00:07:72:9d:dc:4c': {'0 255/255': {'128379': {'CDALJ1/17223002010': '91304'}}},
        '00:0f:bb:fa:25:fd': {'0 255/255': {'232367': {'CDALJ1/14100001093228': '1585097'}}}
    }
}
d2 = {
    '10': {
        '00:07:72:9d:dc:4c': {'0 255/255': {'128379': {'CDALJ1/17223002010': '91310'}}},
        '00:0f:bb:fa:25:fd': {'0 255/255': {'232367': {'CDALJ1/14100001093228': '1585100'}}}
    }
}

print subtract(d2, d1)
```

Formatted output:

```
{
    '10': {
        '00:07:72:9d:dc:4c': {'0 255/255': {'128379': {'CDALJ1/17223002010': '6'}}}, 
        '00:0f:bb:fa:25:fd': {'0 255/255': {'232367': {'CDALJ1/14100001093228': '3'}}}
    }
}
```

Note that the example code fails if your input contains any other types of values than `dict` and `str` that should be interpreted as `int`.